# AWS Amplify White Screen Issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

i have followed various links etc. i am able to publish to aws amplify but i get a white screen.

i am using vss, github and amplify.

i wrote the code

then

npm run build -g

git commit --all -m phil

git push

this is just the basic react app.

i get the following when i inspect the page

GET https://main.d3k27zedi0496.amplifyapp.com/static/js/main.a7eadf0b.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403

any help greatly appreciated

heres my asset-manifest.json on my build directory

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.css": "/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css",
    "main.js": "/static/js/main.a7eadf0b.js",
    "static/js/496.d68808b8.chunk.js": "/static/js/496.d68808b8.chunk.js",
    "static/media/logo.svg": "/static/media/logo.6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.svg",
    "index.html": "/index.html",
    "main.073c9b0a.css.map": "/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css.map",
    "main.a7eadf0b.js.map": "/static/js/main.a7eadf0b.js.map",
    "496.d68808b8.chunk.js.map": "/static/js/496.d68808b8.chunk.js.map"
     },
    "entrypoints": [
```

``` "static/css/main.073c9b0a.css", "static/js/main.a7eadf0b.js" ] }`` ```

`

heres my app.js

```
    import logo from "./logo.svg";
    import "./App.css";
```

`    function App() {
return (

building Application

);
}

export default App;

heres my package.json (i have had it with and without the homepage line)

```
`{
     "name": "workflow", 
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "homepage": "https://main.d3k27zedi0496.amplifyapp.com",
    "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
    },
   "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
        ]
       }
  }``
```

this is my gitignore file

`     # See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

```
 # dependencies
 /node_modules
 /.pnp
 .pnp.js

 # testing
 /coverage

 # production
 /build

 # misc
 .DS_Store
 .env.local
 .env.development.local
 .env.test.local
 .env.production.local

 npm-debug.log*
 yarn-debug.log*
 yarn-error.log*

 #amplify-do-not-edit-begin
 amplify/\#current-cloud-backend
 amplify/.config/local-*
 amplify/logs
 amplify/mock-data
 amplify/mock-api-resources
 amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json
 amplify/backend/.temp
 build/
 dist/
 node_modules/
 aws-exports.js
 awsconfiguration.json
 amplifyconfiguration.json
 amplifyconfiguration.dart
 amplify-build-config.json
 amplify-gradle-config.json
 amplifytools.xcconfig
 .secret-*
 **.sample
 #amplify-do-not-edit-end
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and I resolved it by completely removing: **"homepage": "{URL}"** from my **package.json** and after that I got a strange access denied anytime I tried to navigate to my other pages and found that [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/amplify-aws-access-denied/) solution in case 3 helped.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks i get the following <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>M7K9QKZKKYYM0SN5</RequestId>
<HostId>D2beOu3nsVR4ffCBcSrkyC/fkcat32kvq02rAe9icrQAlI1i1/j0FItqGXwHoQ2pWViL4+7WkBE=</HostId>
</Error>